# consultar y desplegar información de una tabla de bases de datos en base a un formulario de django

Tags: javascript, html5, django

Como consultar los datos de una tabla de base de datos en base al valor de un campo de un formulario en django

Comment: Si te refieres a realizar un filtro de objetos por uno o varios campos del modelo yo recomiendo utilizar django-filter. te adjunto la documentación aquí  https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/

Comment: Muchas gracias,

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, probaré tu recomendación. Lo que necesito es que al ingresar datos al primer campo del formulario, que sería un ID , pueda obtener una información en una etiqueta o nota la cual me indique a que nombre corresponde ese ID en la tabla correspondiente, para asegurarme que el ID existe.

Comment: esa librería sirve para hacer un formulario que filtra por todos los objetos que coincidan con los datos que le introduzcas, al igual es completamente configurable para que puedas realizarlo a tu gusto o necesidades.

Comment: Gracias, F Delgado, utilizaré esa herramienta. Saludos.